# Network Call to Retrieve Steam Game Directory

Tags: networking, steam

I want to programmatically find out the installation directory of a Steam game without having it or Steam installed.

[SteamCMD](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD) has a command called `app_info_print` which can retrieve this information. However, it unfortunately doesn't wait for the network request to finish first and thus is unsuitable for automation. Therefore I want to figure out what Network calls it uses to retrieve this information.

Via WireShark I was able to capture this URL for XCOM2: http://clientconfig.akamai.steamstatic.com/appinfo/268500/sha/163238418f51174e7882ac5faec80da1fe17bbc5.txt.gz. "268500" is the app ID of XCOM2. However, I cannot figure out what input I need to hash in order to get the last part of the URL. I also couldn't find any additional network calls that return the hash.

To my knowledge the [official Steam Web API](https://steamcommunity.com/dev) unfortunately does not provide access to this information.

How can I decipher that hash? Or do there exist any other methods to gain access to this information?

Answer (score 0):

nope only the partner steam api would have this maybe